# set type (in a struct) equal to other struct's member type based on enum value

Tags: c++, templates, struct, enums

Use case: get attributes based on enum value from "a source" and set the values in struct `Attributes`. If value can't be retrieved return an `ErrorCode`:

```
enum class ErrorCode
{
    OK,
    FAILURE
};
enum AttributeType
{
    TYPE1,
    TYPE2,
    TYPE3
};
struct Attributes
{
    uint16_t attribute1;
    uint8_t attribute2;
    bool attribute3;
};
```

Proposed solution: Use a factory where base class defines the interface  method `get` and derived classes (per attribute type) implement the method. Entire `Attributes` object need to be passed to the method and only one member of the struct will be set (based on attribute type) in one implementation.

```
class AttributeRetriever
{
public:
    virtual ErrorCode get(Attributes& attributes) = 0;
};
class Attributetype1 : public AttributeRetriever
{
public:
    ErrorCode get(Attributes& attributes) override
    {
        attributes.attribute1 = 60;
        return ErrorCode::OK;
    }
};
std::unique_ptr<AttributeRetriever> factory(AttributeType at)
{
    if (at == TYPE1) return std::make_unique<Attributetype1>();
    ...
}
```

My solution: Use templates. Instead of passing `Attributes` to method, we return the required value from it. Since we need to return either result value or error, I created a class `Result`. My solution creates a template struct `TypeMap` with enum value as parameter which has `type` equal to the type of attribute in `Attributes` (based on enum value):

```
template <typename ValueType>
class Result
{
public:
    static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<ValueType>::value && std::is_copy_assignable<ValueType>::value, "ValueType must be both copy-constructible and copy-assignable");
    static_assert(std::is_move_constructible<ValueType>::value && std::is_move_assignable<ValueType>::value, "ValueType must be both move-constructible and move-assignable");

    explicit Result(ErrorCode e) noexcept : m_value{}, m_error{e}, m_has_error{true}  {}

    explicit Result(ValueType t) noexcept : m_value{t}, m_error{ErrorCode::OK}, m_has_error{false}  {}

    [[nodiscard]] bool has_value() const noexcept { return !m_has_error; }

    [[nodiscard]] bool has_error() const noexcept { return m_has_error; }

    [[nodiscard]] ValueType value() const noexcept { return m_value; }

    [[nodiscard]] ErrorCode error() const noexcept { return m_error; }

private:
    const ValueType m_value;
    const ErrorCode m_error;
    const bool m_has_error;
};

template<AttributeType> struct TypeMap;

template<>
struct TypeMap<AttributeType::TYPE1>
{
    using type = decltype(Attributes::attribute1);
};

template<>
struct TypeMap<AttributeType::TYPE2>
{
    using type = decltype(Attributes::attribute2);
};

template<>
struct TypeMap<AttributeType::TYPE3>
{
    using type = decltype(Attributes::attribute3);
};

class AttributeRetriever
{
public:
    template<AttributeType AT>
    Result<typename TypeMap<AT>::type> get()
    {
        using R = Result<typename TypeMap<AT>::type>;

        if constexpr(AT == AttributeType::TYPE1)
        {
            return R(60);
        }
        else if (AT == AttributeType::TYPE2)
        {
            return R(3);
        }
        else if (AT == AttributeType::TYPE3)
        {
            return R(false);
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
    AttributeRetriever ar;
    std::cout << ar.get<AttributeType::TYPE1>().value() << '\n';
    std::cout << static_cast<uint32_t>(ar.get<AttributeType::TYPE2>().value()) << '\n';
    std::cout << ar.get<AttributeType::TYPE3>().value() << '\n';
}
```

My solution works. But `TypeMap` needs to be specialized for each attribute type and struct member. Is there a more elegant solution for `TypeMap`?

Comment: What is the underlying problem that you need to solve? Why do you think this solution will solve the problem? What is your design? What are your requirements and their analysis? The problem you ask about is either because you misunderstand the design or how to implement it, or it's the design itself which is flawed. IMO.

Comment: @kiner_shah You misunderstand: you seem to be going the wrong way in an attempt to solve some kind of problem. What is the problem you are trying to solve with the code?

Comment: I want to get the attributes from that class by giving the enum value, the type should be equal to that of struct because the returned attribute values will be stored in the struct. With this question, I am trying to find an elegant way for TypeMap, without template specialization if possible.

Comment: [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional). No need to specialize the whole class

Comment: In a way you are still describing HOW you want to achieve something, but the WHAT is still not clear. I would expect a description that is something like "Given an enum value, I want create an object through a factory method that can initialize and access a member variable of a struct". What you show me now, looks like a lot of accidental complexity

Comment: I apologize, couldn't clarify it properly. I want is this: "I want to return a Result from get function based on enum value. The get function fetches values from "somewhere" and returns the Result. Since the result will be used to initialize a struct member, the type of Result value should be same as that of struct member". I hope this helps.

Comment: This now really sounds like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should show the function that returns that values of different type. "I want to return a Result from get function based on enum value." -> make the return type `auto` and let the compiler figure out the right type for you. If thats what you need then most of the code you have shown here you do not need

Comment: frankly, `// some members and functions` is unnecessary obfuscation. This seems to be the core of the issue you are dealing with, the constructors you want to call and the members you want to initialize. Please post an actual [mcve]

Comment: Apologies, I reframed the entire question. Hopefully now it's clearer.

Comment: Your "Use case" could use more details. Based on what is written for the use case, I would come up with a **much** simpler solution that probably does not match your intended use case: use a switch, as in `switch (attribute_type) { case TYPE1: dest.attribute1 = source.get1(); break; /* etc. */ }`. Let's verify: *"get attributes based on enum value"* -- check -- *"from 'a source'"* -- check -- *"and set the values in struct `Attributes`"* -- check. **What is it about your use case that requires the complications of the solutions?**

Comment: @JaMiT, I forgot to mention about ErrorCode before, added to use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to shorten your type map to:

```
template<AE i>
using TypeMap = typename std::tuple_element<i, std::tuple<
  decltype(A::a),
  decltype(A::b)
>>::type;
```

Answer (score 2):

C++ doesn't support this kind of reflection: you cannot easily access the order in which struct fields are declared. With the exception of initialization order in constructors or manually analyzing offsets, the following struct

```cpp
struct Attributes
{
  uint8_t attribute2;
  uint16_t attribute1;
  bool attribute3;
};
```

will be equivalent to your `Attributes`.
There are existing roundabout solutions like "[magic get](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get)", but normally there are two ways to do something similar.

a) Pointers-to-members. You can use them as template parameters:

```cpp
template<auto m> struct field_helper;
template<typename T, typename FieldType, FieldType T::*memberPtr>
struct field_helper<memberPtr> {
    static FieldType get(const T* ptr){ return ptr->*memberPtr; }
};
```

In this case, your enum vanishes completely: it merges with field names, removing the duplication. If you don't need a code to iterate over every struct field, I recommend trying to go this route.

b) Macros. You can declare fields with a macro that creates a struct specialization for each class member:

```cpp
#define DECLARE_FIELD(IDX, Type, name) Type name; \
  template<typename C> struct field_helper<IDX, C> { \
    static Type get(MainType* ptr) { return ptr->name; } \
  }

struct Atrributes {
    //need typedef since you can't get type name within the type
    typedef Attributes MainType;
    //need extra template parameter to prevent full specialization
    template<int idx, typename = void> struct field_helper;
    DECLARE_FIELD(0, uint16_t, attribute1);
    //...
};
```

With this, all fields are explicitly numbered: you can count them, iterate over them, access their type by the index, etc. (You can make numbering automatic with more macro work but this goes beyond the scope of your question.)